# Debugging exception no longer working

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8

I am developing for Windows Phone 8, and recently, not sure what I have done, the debugger no longer throw me the line number of the CS file where exception occur.

This is the only message I get (TaskHost)

Unhandled exception at 0x76C91EDB (KERNELBASE.DLL) in TaskHost.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x80131604, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x70290000).

I hope someone can help me, to reconfig Visual Studio to show me the exact line number where the exception occurs.

Comment: It is a TargetInvocationException, definitely managed code.  You give way too few breadcrumbs, quacks like you are debugging with the native debugging engine instead of the managed one.  Try this first with a simple "hello world" app that throws an exception intentionally, shows you whether it is VS or the project.

Comment: I try "throw new NotImplementedException();", it still shows TaskHost.exe error. I created a new project and it works normally. So something must be wrong within my project settings?

Answer (score 2):

Issue found. In project properties > Debug > UI Task

The value somehow is "Native only". I changed it back to "Managed Only" and it works.
Thanks @Hans Passant for tips.